# Why is the group determinant important

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, math-history

The representation theory of finite groups was arguably invented by Frobenius to factorize the group determinant. Can you tell me *why* he wanted to do this, and what is so important about the group determinant?

Comment: Discussed on MO here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/36046/290